# Should I contact our boss if my coworker stole a computer from me?

Tags: ethics

I am a nurse and this other nurse asked to buy my computer and stated she would pay me on Zelle.  She has never paid me and now is ghosting me.  Should I involve our boss as we work for the same organization.

Also, she has a ethical mark on her license with state that is barring her from continuing her education to advance her degree.

Comment: File a report with your local law enforcement and let them handle it.

Comment: This is a personal matter, not a work relayed matter. Do not involve your employer or your manager in this.

Comment: @sf02 Though it's unlikely law enforcement will be able to do anything- debt disputes are a civil matter.

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim This depends on jurisdiction.  What the OP described can be considered a form of fraud in many locations and could fall under criminal penalties.

Comment: As others have suggested this has nothing to do with the workplace. So you are ready to file a civil case to collect the money, contact this individual, in such a way it cannot be avoided politely and with respect

Answer (score 9):

**No**. This is a personal dispute, keep work out of it.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have confused your boss with your mom, or perhaps a teacher. Their job is to manage things- not to settle personal conflicts between you and your coworkers. Unless the fact that a coworker is ghosting you is affecting your job, do not mention this. If it is, focus on that, not on your personal problems.

> Also, she has ethical mark on her license with state which is baring her from continuing her education to advance her degree.

And? Is verifying your coworker's degree part of your job role? Or are you just slinging shit at someone you're mad at in the hope that it'll magically get your money back (it won't and if anything her losing her job will make it harder to pay you back).

If you're determined to get your money back, get every piece of communication you have to prove this was a loan and not a gift and file in Small Claims Court. Though, honestly, you're at the annoying hundreds of dollars level where it's not enough to be worth the time and cost.

Consider this a life lesson- never lend money to someone unless you're ok with losing it.